# products.map is not a function

Tags: reactjs, import

im trying to consume an API from here https://api.agify.io/?name=bella  but im gettin an error, products.map is not a function, im not sure what im doing wrong.

```
function Table(){
    const [products, setProducts] = useState([])
    useEffect(()=>{
            async function loadProducts(){
                const response = await api.get('')
              setProducts(response.data)
            }

            loadProducts()
    }, [])
    return(
        <Container>
        <h3>Tabela de produtos</h3>
        <Ptable>
      <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Code</th>
        <th>Price</th>
      </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {products.map((products)=>(
          <tr >
            <td>{products._age}</td>
            <td>{products._count}</td>
            <td>{products._name}</td>
          </tr>
        ))}
      </tbody>
    </Ptable>
        </Container>
    )
}

export default Table
```

Answer (score 0):

The return value of the API is an object and not an array.({"name":"bella","age":34,"count":40138}) . You need to return an array.